# Python Pandas to merge two dataframes without changing the order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas Dataframes, one is **df1** with shape = (35,9), the other is **df2** with shape = (12,9) and I want to merge them.

The row index of  df2 is:

```
RangeIndex(start=1, stop=13, step=1)
```

The row index of df1 is:

```
Int64Index([    2, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     3, 10021, 10022, 10023,
        10024,     4, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     5, 10021, 10022,
        10023, 10024,     6, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     7, 10021,
        10022, 10023, 10024,     8, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024],
       dtype='int64')
```

i want to merge these two dataframes so that the resulting dataframe has the following index:

```
Int64Index([1,2,10021,10022,10023,10024, 3, 10021, 10022, 10023,
        10024,     4, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     5, 10021, 10022,
        10023, 10024,     6, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     7, 10021,
        10022, 10023, 10024,     8, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 9, 10, 11, 12],
       dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Why do the indexes from df1 and df2 have the same name? For example, df1 has an index `2` and df2 also has an index `2`. Are the rows the same then? So what will happen with the merge conflict when df1's indexes are the same as df2's indexes? It seems like you just want df2's indexes `1, 9, 10, 11, 12` added to df1's indexes. Is this true?

Comment: Hi, yes, the rows are same having same value in the two dataframes. For all the places, where indices are repeated, only one instance has to be taken into account.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for an `outer join`:

```
import pandas as pd
idx1 = [    2, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     3, 10021, 10022, 10023,
        10024,     4, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     5, 10021, 10022,
        10023, 10024,     6, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024,     7, 10021,
        10022, 10023, 10024,     8, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'a': range(len(idx1))},
                   index=idx1)


df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'b': range(1,13)},
                   index=range(1,13))

result_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)
result_df.index
Int64Index([    1,     2,     3,     4,     5,     6,     7,     8,     9,
               10,    11,    12,    13, 10021, 10021, 10021, 10021, 10021,
            10021, 10021, 10022, 10022, 10022, 10022, 10022, 10022, 10022,
            10023, 10023, 10023, 10023, 10023, 10023, 10023, 10024, 10024,
            10024, 10024, 10024, 10024, 10024],
          dtype='int64')
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reverting back; although, an outer join or a union of these does the work, however, it doesn't keep the order in which the result is desired. What I am looking for is the sequence to be maintained, i.e., after 2 it has to have 10021 and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

desired_idx = [1, 2, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 3, 10021, 10022, 10023,
               10024, 4, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 5, 10021, 10022,
               10023, 10024, 6, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 7, 10021,
               10022, 10023, 10024, 8, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 9, 10, 11, 12]

idx1 = [2, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 3, 10021, 10022, 10023,
        10024, 4, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 5, 10021, 10022,
        10023, 10024, 6, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024, 7, 10021,
        10022, 10023, 10024, 8, 10021, 10022, 10023, 10024]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((35,9)), index=idx1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((12,9)), index=range(1,13))

df_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', left_index=True, right_index=True)\
             .reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='index')

df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=df_merge.columns)

for i, idx in enumerate(desired_idx):
    df.loc[i] = df_merge[df_merge['index'] == idx].values.flatten()

df.set_index('index', inplace=True)
df.index = df.index.astype(int)
df
```

I continued with the work from the answer below. We have to remove the duplicates then iterate through our desired indexes and append them to a new dataframe. I tried many different methods and this one was the only one to work because Pandas sorts the indexes when using built-in functions.

Comment: Hi, thanks a ton; this is helpful :) I have managed to  change the indices in ascending order ( by changing the indices of the middle four repetitive rows) and then applied a union of the two dataframes for my present project.